# using a method with a func argument in System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, iqueryable

I am using a method Rank to get the rank of the product using some custom logic like this:

```
product.Rank(p=>p.Price);

public class Product
{
     public double Price {get;}
     public int Rank(Func<Product, double> compfunc)
     {
     ...
     }
}
```

I would like to use this method in the where clause using the extension library [`System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

for example:

```
products.Where("Rank(p=>p.Price) == 0")
```

Although the above doesn't work. 
Is it possible to pass the function like this?

Comment: You might be able to create an extension method for the IQueryable that takes in the lambda and calls Rank and Where internally...

Comment: Why do you want to use the string for a query like this?

Comment: I am trying to build a custom expression builder for the user, so one could build some conditions/criteria from a predefined set of properties. Using string for building the expression internally seems a good option to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do this:

```
products.Where("Rank(@0) == 0", new Func<Product, double>(p => p.Price));
```